# GitHub branch with partial read/write access

Tags: github

I have a GitHub repository for my web application.  I have a freelance graphics designer who is about to do some work for me.  What I would like to do is create a branch for him which only allows him read and write access to specific files.  For example he needs access to all of the interface html/css/js, but I don't want him to be able to download the source code for the entire application.  Is there a way to do this with branching or do I have to create a separate repository all together which only contains the files I want him to access?

Thanks for any help.